# Statement lambda with parameter from delegate

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, delegates

Basically I'm trying to understand [WrapCallback](http://www.markermetro.com/2013/01/technical/handling-unhandled-exceptions-with-asyncawait-on-windows-8-and-windows-phone-8/):

```
private static SendOrPostCallback WrapCallback(SendOrPostCallback sendOrPostCallback)
{
    return state =>
    {
        // do something
    };
}
```

Here a [Statement Lambda](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx#Anchor_1) and a [Delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms173176.aspx) is used:

`delegate void System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback(object state)`

`state` is the input parameter of the `SendOrPostCallback` delegate and it is also the input parameter of the statement lambda. But what is actually returned here? The delegate again? How?

I also tried to make an example to understand that better, but some parts are missing. Only *Hello* is written to the console.

```
delegate void TestDelegate(string s);

public static void Main()
{
    TestDelegate del = new TestDelegate(Notify);
    del("Hello");
    WrapCallback(del);
}

private static void Notify(string name)
{
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}

private static TestDelegate WrapCallback(TestDelegate testDelegate)
{
    return s => {
        Console.WriteLine("test");
    };
}
```

Can someone explain the behavior of `WrapCallback` to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, let's think of scenario - we need to display "Operation is started" in console before we do something, then we'd like to do some operation and finally display: "Operation is finished".

We can achieve this with logic that is very close to one used in this `SendOrPostCallback` from your example. For sake of simplicity our business operation is calculation of number's square. The code is:

```
    static Action<object> WrapOperation(Action<object> action)
    {
        return new Action<object>(
            obj =>
        {
            Console.Write("Operation is started  ");
            Thread.Sleep(1500);

            action.Invoke(obj);

            Thread.Sleep(1500);
            Console.Write("   " + "Operation is finished");
        });
    }
```

And Main is :

```
        Action<object> someBusinessOperation = x => Console.Write((int)x * (int)x);

        Action<object> wrappedOperation = WrapOperation(someBusinessOperation);

        wrappedOperation(9);

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Output :  `Operation is started   81   Operation is finished`

So what's going on here ?

--- In this line of code we create function :

```
Action<object> someBusinessOperation = x => Console.WriteLine((int)x * (int)x);
```

--- WrapOperation method simply accepts delegate as parameter and then creates and returns a new delegate instance. Note that for this point we haven't invoked any methods yet, we just let `WrapOperation` to wrap delegate and return another delegate.

Finally we invoke the method with that delegate and pass parameter :

```
wrappedOperation(9);
```

P.S.

When we pass 9 to `wrappedOperation` it is injected in method as `obj` parameter and this method does it's own logic but then re-use through delegate `someBusinessOperation` method (this `x => Console.Write((int)x * (int)x)`) and passes this object inside this function as `x`. So instead of just one function that accepts object as parameter we create function that accept object but does some extra logic before and after invoking of `someBusinessOperation`.

It is worth mentioning that when we use parameter `action` inside of our lambda we use something called *[closure](http://www.codethinked.com/c-closures-explained)* (capture of variable from external scope)

Comment: What is `obj` in your example? Is it the delegate? Where does it come from? It's nowhere defined?

Comment: @grabner As you probably noticed we return `Action<object>` in `WrapOperation` method. To pass some method with this delegate the method should accept one parameter of type `object` and return `void`. Our object is this object parameter that method (in our case it's lambda expression) accepts.

Comment: @grabner Basically when we use lamda expression syntax it's the same as when we use normal methods with only difference that lamda method is anonymous and it is not possible to use it *without delegate*. So if we type something like `var a = () => Console.Write();` compiler simply creates `Action` delegate for us automatically. You can check it while debugging if you place a breakpoint right after it and put mouse cursor over `a` to see what type does it have.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! Why does it work to use `return obj` instead of `return new Action<object>(obj => {});`? I get the same result. What happens here? So `WrapOperation` is returning `void` despite its signature?

Comment: Well, this code : `static Action<object> WrapOperation(Action<object> action){ return obj;}` will not compile because compiler doesn't know what `obj` stands for.

Comment: I mean this `static Action<object> WrapOperation(Action<object> action){ return obj => { /* do something */ } }`. It does work like your example, but why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112872/discussion-between-fabjan-and-grabner).

Answer (score 1):

In your example code WrapCallback is returning the delegate

```
s => {
    Console.WriteLine("test");
};
```

In your Main method you are calling WrapCallback, which returns that delegate but you don't do anything with it so it never prints anything to the console.

If you make the following changes to your Main method, it will print "test".

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        TestDelegate del = new TestDelegate(Notify);
        del("Hello");
        //Store the return value in a new delegate
        TestDelegate del2 = WrapCallback(del);
        //And then call that delegate.  Note that TestDelegate takes a string as a parameter
        del2("This string does nothing");
        //Alternatively, call the delegate at the same time it's returned, but don't store it
        WrapCallback(del)("This string does nothing");
    }
```

Comment: If I do a `Console.WriteLine` then I get `Program+TestDelegate`. But that's not what I'm expecting. *test* is never print out. Why?

Comment: @grabner I added some more code to my answer.  Let me know if you still have questions.

Answer (score 1):

WrapCallback returns a function (that accepts a string parameter s). You still need to pass it an argument in order to execute.

```
TestDelegate del2 = WrapCallback(del);
del2("something"); //prints "test"
```

Answer (score 1):

> But what is actually returned here? The delegate again?

Not *the* delegate but a *new* delegate is returned. The old delegate is discarded.

Here's a simpler rewrite:

```
private static TestDelegate WrapCallback(TestDelegate testDelegate /*ignored*/)
{
    TestDelegate result = (s => {
        Console.WriteLine("test");
    });
    return result;
}
```